# How to configure apt-listchanges to send a unique summary email when running unattended-upgrades

Tags: apt, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

I'm currently on Debian 10, and updates are applied with the `unattended-upgrades` tool.

I wish `apt-listchanges` to send me a **unique summary mail per machine** as it did with Debian 9; but it sends a `changelogs` mail per package updated per machine. This spam makes this tool useless but I was not able to apply the right configurations to meet my needs.

Here are my configuration files:

```
# /etc/apt/listchanges.conf
[apt]
frontend=pager
email_address=root
confirm=0
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=both
no_network=false
email_format=text
headers=false
reverse=false
```

```
# /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
[...]
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "<it mail>";
Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "false";
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem was from `unattended-upgrades`: from the `buster` version, a `minimal steps` system was introduced

> // Split the upgrade into the smallest possible chunks so that
>
> // they can be interrupted with SIGTERM. This makes the upgrade
>
> // a bit slower but it has the benefit that shutdown while a upgrade
>
> // is running is possible (with a small delay)
>
> //Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";

Because each package is by default upgraded independently than the others, the `apt-listchanges` program was called multiple times and so the upgrade process sent a mail per package updated per machine.

To resolve the issue, I just changed the parameter with `Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "false";`; I hope it will help others =)